# PyQt QHBoxLayout inside QPushButton text is being truncated

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to place a checkbox and some text inside a button, but I'm having trouble getting the button to expand wide enough to see the full text.

[image]

```
self.check = QtGui.QCheckBox("long text", self)
self.checkLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
self.checkLayout.addWidget(self.check)
self.checkButton = QtGui.QPushButton(None, self)
self.checkButton.setLayout(self.checkLayout)
```

I've tried various combinations of adding stretches, setting the size policy, setting margins and styles etc. but haven't had any luck so far.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Add a layout to the button. Place the checkbox inside the layout. Looks like this is the only way for QWidget to automatically track a size of its subwidgets. 
But QWidget doesn't automatically resize itself to fit its content. You must invoke `adjustSize` function to do it.

```
class TestWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        self.check = QtGui.QCheckBox("very very long text")

        self.checkLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.checkLayout.addWidget(self.check)

        self.checkButton = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.checkButton.setLayout(self.checkLayout)
        self.checkButton.adjustSize()

        self.checkButton.setParent(self)
```

**UPD**: There is a problem with `adjustSize`. This function doesn't work for me if I call it **after** adding `checkButton` to the screen:

```
# works
self.checkButton.adjustSize()
self.checkButton.setParent(self)
# doesn't work
self.checkButton.setParent(self)
self.checkButton.adjustSize()
```

My solution is manual resizing instead of calling `adjustSize`:

```
self.checkButton.setFixedSize(self.checkLayout.sizeHint())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still having trouble getting it to work though. When I call setFixedSize(), I can see the .size() update correctly in the button (although the sizehint is still too small - I believe this is expected), but it's still displayed on screen with a small size. I've tried re-ordering the statements and the setting the parent too..any ideas?

Comment: Well, there's something strange here. I haven't managed to reproduce your trouble. If the problem is in sizeHint() function, I can only suggest  ugly monkey patching: `self.checkButton.sizeHint = self.checkButton.size`.